# How does end-to-end encryption work with whatsapp web as of 2022?

Tags: mobile, whatsapp, instant-messaging, end-to-end-encryption

The accepted answer to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119552/how-does-end-to-end-encryption-work-with-whatsapp-web) is now outdated, since Whatsapp web [does not require](https://www.republicworld.com/technology-news/apps/how-to-use-whatsapp-web-without-connecting-via-smartphone-heres-a-step-by-step-guide.html) an online smartphone to function anymore. How is the key exchange performed securely?

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but here is the [whitepaper](https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.8562-6/271639644_1080641699441889_2201546141855802968_n.pdf?_nc_cat=108&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=ad8a9d&_nc_ohc=pKFueeyg0AwAX-smkyb&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.xx&oh=00_AT9Gqm1l-cdQ5DvltTgsDS-cmc4tBvaPpQv-_aUUwkk7Vg&oe=625A16BD). The parts on companion devices apply, I believe.

Comment: “URL signature expired”